# for loop prints multiple dictionaries how to combine them into one dictionary

Tags: python-2.7

```
for cf in custfield:
    """names and values in custom field """
        names = cf.get('Name')
        dlda ={}
        dlda[names] = cf.get('Value')
        print dlda
```

output:

```
{u'DL LISTED NUMBER': u'7199990011'}
{u'DL LAST NAME': u'GOODMAN'}
{u'DL FIRST NAME': u'Ms.'}
{u'DL DUAL NAME': u'NO'}
{u'DL SUPRS ADDRESS': u'NO'}
{u'DL DUAL FIRST NAME ': u'Ms.'}
{u'DL DUAL LAST NAME ': u'GOODMAN'}
{u'DL ZIP': u'80902'}
{u'DL STATE': u'CO'}
{u'DL CITY': u'COLORADO SPRINGS'}
{u'DL ADDRESS 1': u'6043 VERDUN LOOP APT C'}
{u'DL LISTING ADDRESS': u'TRUE'}
```

result should be like:

```
{u'DL LISTED NUMBER': u'7199990011',
 u'DL LAST NAME': u'GOODMAN',
 u'DL FIRST NAME': u'Ms.'.....}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The minimal change you need to do is to define the dictionary outside of the loop:

```
dlda = {}
for cf in custfield:
    """names and values in custom field """
    names = cf.get('Name')
    dlda[names] = cf.get('Value')
print dlda
```

it should also be possible to use a generator for such a simple task, but I cannot test without mocking the custfield object:

```
print dict((cf.get('Name'), cf.get('Value')) for cf in custfield)
```